# Order of execution issue- WF rules, AfterUpdate doesn't fire

Tags: trigger, workflow, order-of-execution

I update an account record (lets say 1st record), in the debug log, I see BeforeUpdate is fired, validation rules , but nothing else - like workflow rules, duplicate rules, AfterUpdate 
In another account record (lets say 2nd record), it's seems to be working fine , Validation rule WF rules, duplicate rule. 
However, in the 1st record, there is a validation rule error which doesn't allow record to be saved. **But, it shouldn't stop from running other transaction events (WF rules, Duplicate rules, AfterUpdate etc) , or does it**? 
I referred the doc- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm , but nothing as mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But, it shouldn't stop from running other transaction events (WF rules, Duplicate rules, AfterUpdate etc) , or does it?

Yes, it does. The order of execution stops when an record is unable to be saved or otherwise causes an exception to be thrown. No further automation will run on that record. Failing to do so would cause your database to be left in an inconsistent state, or simply accumulate more work for Salesforce to roll back due to an unhandled exception.